# Laravel Pagination

Tags: база-данных, laravel, pagination

Добрый день. Начал изучать Laravel. Возникла проблема со страничным выводом.

**Имеется контроллер:**

[image: IndexController]

**Реализовал постраничный вывод новостей:**

[image: output news]

Проблема в том, что при переходе на вторую страницу, информация с баннера, интересных новостей, блока обо мне исчезает.

**Первая страница:**
[image: first page]

**Вторая страница:**
[image: last page]

Объясните новичку что не так, и куда девается информация.

Comment: сколько у вас баннера?

Comment: Один единственный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё просто, если посмотрите на метод [paginate](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L706), увидите что третий параметр отвечает за название параметра в котором будет передаваться номер страницы, по умолчанию это `page`.

В вашем же случае получается что все пагинаторы берут значение страницы с этого параметра и если где-то переключаете страницу, она меняется на всех пагинаторах. Чтобы они не зависели друг от друга измените третий параметр, к примеру:

```
$banners = Banners::paginate(1, ['*'], 'banners-page');
```

Теперь баннеры не будут зависеть от других пагинаторов, и нужно так сделать со всеми, но вот только если честно не пойму зачем вы используете метод `paginate` везде, там же она не нужна, используйте `one`, `all`, `get`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Второй раз выручаете.

Comment: @АндрейКононов да так совпало :) И на будущее если вам не нужна пагинация - не используйте её, в ларавел есть много вариаций вывода данных.